# No block are producing in substrate parachain template

Tags: substrate-node-template, substrate-parachain-template

I am using [`substrate parachain template`](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-parachain-template). I run node using `./target/release/parachain-template-node --dev` command. No block are producing. Should I need to add `pallet-grandpa` as well?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Running the parachain-template is different than running the substrate-node-template.

In order to run the parachain-template, you need to follow this tutorial:

- https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/build-a-parachain